# How to add user to Sentry in Symfony4 for all exceptions?

Tags: symfony4, sentry

I added Sentry to my project, but it doesn't add the currently logged in user for some events.

I added an event subscriber, but I'm not sure anymore if I really need it. For excepctions like ArgumentCountError everything works fine. For  NotFoundHttpException it doesn't. After a bit of debugging I found, that ExceptionListener->onKernelRequest isn't called with every exception. I already emptied skip_capture in sentry.yaml, but this didn't help.
What am I missing. My guess would be that propagation is stopped somewhere. But where? And how can I change this?

```
<?php
// src/EventSubscriber/SentrySubscriber

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Sentry\SentryBundle\SentrySymfonyEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;

class SentrySubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    /** @var \Raven_Client */
    protected $client;
    private $username;

    public function __construct(\Raven_Client $client) {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            SentrySymfonyEvents::PRE_CAPTURE => 'preCapture',
            SentrySymfonyEvents::SET_USER_CONTEXT => 'setUserContext',
        );
    }

    public function preCapture(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event, $eventName, EventDispatcher $dispatcher) {
// username is empty, because setUserContext wasn't executed
// echo 'preCapture';var_dump($this->username);var_dump($this->client->_user);
        $this->client->user_context(['username' => $this->username]);
    }

    public function setUserContext(\Sentry\SentryBundle\Event\SentryUserContextEvent $event) {
//      echo 'setUserContext';      var_dump($event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUsername());
        $this->username = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUsername();
    }

}
```

My config:

```
// config/services.yaml
services:
    App\EventSubscriber\SentrySubscriber:
        arguments:
          - '@sentry.client'
        tags:
          - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }

// config/packages/sentry.yaml
sentry:
    dsn: '%env(SENTRY_DSN)%'
    options:
        curl_method: async
        release: '%env(RELEASE)%'

    skip_capture: # nothing else here, because everything should be captured
```

Answer (score 4):

Sentry doesn't send user data by default to prevent issues with GDPR and similar regulations.

If you want to re-enable sending user data, add this to `sentry.yaml`:

```
sentry:
    options:
        send_default_pii: true
```

Official docs [here](https://docs.sentry.io/data-management/sensitive-data/).

The check is implemented in `\Sentry\SentryBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest`.

Comment: The docs link is now a 404, alas. Does anyone know how to do it in 2022?

Comment: @cheryllium The snippet I've posted is still relevant, I think. If it doesn't work for you, what errors are you getting? You can print reference config with `bin/console config:dump-reference sentry`.

Comment: Sorry @gronostaj - I didn't try it yet as I wanted to read the docs first so I understand what I'm copy-pasting, and can adapt it to my use case. My use case is a little more complex - the app has different kinds of users and I want to customize what gets sent for each.

Comment: It would be fantastic if you could point me to a non-404 docs page on sentry about it? I just couldn't find one

Comment: @cheryllium Here's an [archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20200807135317/https://docs.sentry.io/data-management/sensitive-data/). There's barely anything about the config there though. I don't think the official bundle allows for per-user PII control - you may have to implement it yourself.

Comment: I found current docs, and got it working in my app. For future readers- Here's [send-default-pii config](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/symfony/configuration/options/#send-default-pii) and [this is how you customize the user info sent.](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/symfony/enriching-events/identify-user/)